# Does python logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler allow creation of a group writable log file?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm using the standard python (2.5.2) logging module, specifically the `RotatingFileHandler`, on a linux system.  My application supports both a command-line interface and a web-service interface.  I would like to have both write to the same log file.  However, when the log file gets rotated, the new file has `644` permissions and is owned by the web server user which prevents the command-line user from writing to it.  Can I specify that new log files should be group-writable in the logging configuration or during logging initialization?

I have looked into the `mode` setting (`r`/`w`/`a`), but it doesn't seem to support any file permissions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I resorted to scanning the logging.handlers module and was unable to see any way to specify a different file permissions mode. So, I have a solution now based on extending the RotatingFileHandler as a custom handler.  It was fairly painless, once I found some nice references to creating one.  The code for the custom handler is below.

```
class GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler(handlers.RotatingFileHandler):

    def doRollover(self):
        """
        Override base class method to make the new log file group writable.
        """
        # Rotate the file first.
        handlers.RotatingFileHandler.doRollover(self)

        # Add group write to the current permissions.
        currMode = os.stat(self.baseFilename).st_mode
        os.chmod(self.baseFilename, currMode | stat.S_IWGRP)
```

I also discovered that to reference the custom handler from a logging config file, I had to bind my module to the logging namespace.  Simple to do, but annoying.

```
from mynamespace.logging import custom_handlers
logging.custom_handlers = custom_handlers
```

References I found useful:
[binding custom handlers](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-October/634318.html) and
[creating custom handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935930/creating-a-logging-handler-to-connect-to-oracle/1014450#1014450)

Comment: I was just about to post the same solution :P

Comment: One thing missing from this solution is doing the chmod on the creation of log file the first time it is created.

Comment: How do you fix that? The first time file creation

Comment: for fixing the creation time permissions, may be override _open as in @rob 's answer

Comment: to update permissions/ownership of the logfile when it is first created, you can add the relevant `os` operations inside of an `__init__()` method after first calling `super()` (see answer by @DennisLi below)

Answer (score 33):

Here is a slightly better solution. this overrides the _open method that is used. setting the umask before creating then returning it back to what it was.

```
class GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):    
    def _open(self):
        prevumask=os.umask(0o002)
        #os.fdopen(os.open('/path/to/file', os.O_WRONLY, 0600))
        rtv=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler._open(self)
        os.umask(prevumask)
        return rtv
```

Comment: What if the application crashes while opening ? Does the umask stay set with 0o002

Comment: @BenjaminToueg I think it's specific to that process and doesn't affect the system default umask.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution worked fine:

```
import os

class GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler(handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        os.chmod(self.baseFilename, 0o0777)  # You can change whatever permission you want here.

        # you can also change the group of the file:
        os.chown(self.baseFilename, uid, gid)   # pass the user_id and group_id you want to set
```

Comment: It seems that doesn't work. If change the log files to be owned by root, and give all of the the permission of "0o0777", it throws `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'some_handler': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: `. It looks that the process owner needs to have the ownership of the log files.

Comment: I think this is only the permission issue. in your case, you might need `sudo` to change the file permission, you can test it with command-line first. if so, you can change os.chmod, os.chown two lines to a sudo version code.

Comment: However the `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'some_handler': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:` was gone, if using `handlers.RotatingFileHandler`, and the log file with the permission of `0o0666`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete solution for Django based on [rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856395/rob)'s solution. in `my_module` :

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
```

The `class=` that happens during the logging configuration is evaluated in the namespace of the logging module, and by default this does not have a binding to handlers. So we have to put it in explicitly before we can extend it. See [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054864/use-fileconfig-to-configure-custom-handlers-in-python)

```
logging.handlers = logging.handlers
```

It's this magical incantation that took me forever to find - I couldn't believe it did anything! Finally, Jon's class will load without errors.

```
class GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):    
    def _open(self):
        prevumask = os.umask(0o002)
        rtv = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler._open(self)
        os.umask(prevumask)
        return rtv
```

To use this for Django add the following this in the settings file

```
from my_module import GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler
logging.handlers.GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler = GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler
```

And then in `LOGGING['handlers']['file']` you have

```
'class': 'logging.handlers.GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler'
```

Answer (score 1):

James Gardner has written a handler that only rotates files, not creating or deleting them:
http://packages.python.org/logrotate/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$ chgrp loggroup logdir
$ chmod g+w logdir
$ chmod g+s logdir
$ usermod -a -G loggroup myuser
$ umask 0002
```

Comment: could you explain or at least give a short comment what the commands do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that `def _open(self):` worked with `umask(0o000)` to get all the permissions of `-rw-rw-rw-`.

`os.chmod(self.baseFilename, 0o0777)` failed with `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'some_handler': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:` if the log file has ownership of `root:root` that's different from running process's, such as `testuser`.

```
from logging import handlers

import logging
import os

class GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler(handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    def _open(self):
        prevumask = os.umask(0o000)  # -rw-rw-rw-
        rtv = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler._open(self)
        os.umask(prevumask)
        return rtv

LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'db_handler': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'log.GroupWriteRotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': PATH_TO_LOGS + '/db.log',
                'maxBytes': maxBytes,
                'backupCount': backupCount,
                'formatter': 'standard',
        },
```

Log files:

```
logs]# ls -lrt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 71 Apr  1 16:02 db.log

logs]# ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 testuser testuser 0 Apr  1 16:20 db.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what described here is an anti-pattern - different processes should not write data into the same file.

And non of the solutions above worked for me, causing different permissions issues in different scenarios.

As a temp workaround I've added a random suffix into the log filename so each process will get a unique filename on a startup.

The proper way to solve this issue - have a centralized log handler (log server), e.g. rsyslog.