# Python: create logging custom handler and configure existing config file to redirect logs to Output widget

Tags: python-3.x, logging, widget, handler, jupyter-lab

**Note: this is my very first post. I tried searching for my answer first, apologies for not finding if it already exists. If I do anything wrong with this post, notify me, teach me, help me improve.**

I have a Python script separated in different classes, using the logging module to display various messages. The logging setup is done through the following configuration file :

```
[loggers]
keys=root, main , [...list of loggers...]

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, fileHandler
qualname=main
propagate=0

[...all loggers...]

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('logconfig.log',)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
class=logging.Formatter
```

Which is then called in the script at the beginning of each module like this:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('main')
```

This is working very fine when running the script alone.

Now, I need to run my script in a Jupyter notebook through the *%run* magic command, which also works fine. But from there what I want to do is redirect any output from logging to an Output widget. So, in a previous cell from running the script, I (try to) declare a custom handler:

```
class OutputWidgetHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    """ Custom logging handler sending logs to an output widget """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = {
            'width': '80%',
            'height': '160px',
            'border': '1px solid black'
        }
        self.out = widgets.Output(layout=layout)
        display(self.out)

    def emit(self, record):
        """ Overload of logging.Handler method """
        formatted_record = self.format(record)
        new_output = {
            'name': 'stdout',
            'output_type': 'stream',
            'text': formatted_record+'\n'
        }
        self.out.outputs = (new_output, ) + self.out.outputs
```

That I bind to my configuration file with:

```
logging.handlers.OutputWidgetHandler = OutputWidgetHandler
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

And I update the configuration accordingly with:

```
[handlers]
keys= OutputWidgetHandler, consoleHandler, fileHandler

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
handlers= OutputWidgetHandler, fileHandler
qualname=main
propagate=0

[...]

[handler_OutputWidgetHandler]
class=handlers.OutputWidgetHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

I based my code so far on this answer 
[Use fileConfig to configure custom handlers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054864/use-fileconfig-to-configure-custom-handlers-in-python)

But I seem to be unlucky as when running the script in the following notebook cell, the log output can't seem to connect to the custom `OutpuWidgetHandler`, thus doesn't display anything in the created output widget.

Thanks for helping if you have any clue, any idea is welcome and might solve this. Cheers.