# Django log file permissions with uwsgi

Tags: python, django, file-permissions, uwsgi

I'm using Django with uwsgi. The process runs as `www-data` user which is also the owner of all log files (both for uwsgi & Django). When I use RotatingFileHandler for logging in Django, the new log files are created with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data
```

I've added the the currently logged-in user (`ubuntu`) to `www-data` group but still don't have write permission to the above log files. As a result, I can't run `python manage.py test`.

How can I tell either (i) uwsgi or (ii) logging framework or (iii) file handler to create log files with permissions `0660` so that both `ubuntu` & `www-data` can read/write to the log files.

There's a caveat though, if I run `manage.py test` and logrotation happens at that moment, the new log file would be owned by `ubuntu` user and uwsgi will complain. I don't know if it's possible to fix this with altering the current user/group permission structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does python logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler allow creation of a group writable log file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407474/does-python-logging-handlers-rotatingfilehandler-allow-creation-of-a-group-writa)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to implement your own subclass as demonstrated in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407474/does-python-logging-handlers-rotatingfilehandler-allow-creation-of-a-group-writa)