# python log view application

Tags: python, mysql, logging

I want to have GUI application or Web app where I can view the python log information. I can choose any formatter required. But it should work with standard logging module.

I have configured my logs to  file. But I wanted to have log to be stored to mysql db (it is possible) but I badly need user interface to view the log from remote place.

Any recommended tool or approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a database handler for logging as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935930/creating-a-logging-handler-to-connect-to-oracle/1014450#1014450) using any Python DB-API 2.0 compliant database interface. Then, of course, you can view the logs using any framework which allows you to get and display data via the Web.

Or, you can use log4j's Chainsaw GUI using the approach outlined [here](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Logging#lumberjacking-with-log4j-s-chainsaw). Here's a screenshot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pylonshq.com](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/_images/Pylons_Stack-Chainsaw-OSX.png))</sub>

Just two approaches - there are no doubt numerous others.

Answer (score 0):

vsConsole FileView lets you view server logs via a web application. Have a look at the demo and see if it suits your needs:

http://demo.vamonossoftware.com/