# Python customize logging

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have a webapp (Flask) and I need to enable some logging. I need to log to a mysql table with the columns:

```
id, timestamp, userid, orderid, service, msg, response
```

I would like to use the python's std logging.
Example usage would be:

```
special_logger = logging.getSpecialLogger() # instead of logging.getLogger()

special_logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
special_logger.addHandler(myMysqlHandler)
special_logger.debug(current_uid, myorderid, 'SERVICE1', 'Exception happened', serviceResponse)
```

How I can achieve that?

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a normal logger, and a database handler as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935930/creating-a-logging-handler-to-connect-to-oracle/1014450#1014450). Although my other answer doesn't address MySQL specifically, it uses DB-API and so should be adaptable to a MySQL Python driver which conforms to DB-API 2.0.

**Update:** You can pass extra data to the log by following the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can write an LogHandler. The problem is 
that I need to pass extra data in the logger. Check the last line 
in the code in the question